# Simple Injector (3.1.5) & SignalR (2.2): SimpleInjector.ActivationException

Tags: c#, signalr, simple-injector

I try to implement the [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/232) proposed integration. Unfortunately my hub methods are not called. This exception preventing it:

> SimpleInjector.ActivationException occured.   HResult=-2146233088
>   Message=The disposed object cannot be accessed. Objektname:
>   "SimpleInjector.Scope".   Source=SimpleInjector   StackTrace:
>          bei SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()   InnerException: 
>          HResult=-2146232798
>          Message=The disposed object cannot be accessed. Objektname: "SimpleInjector.Scope".
>          ObjectName=SimpleInjector.Scope
>          Source=SimpleInjector
>          StackTrace:
>               bei SimpleInjector.Scope.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
>               bei SimpleInjector.Scope.RequiresInstanceNotDisposed()
>               bei SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstance[TService,TImplementation](ScopedRegistration2
>   registration)
>               bei SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstance[TService,TImplementation](ScopedRegistration2
>   registration, Scope scope)
>               bei SimpleInjector.Advanced.Internal.LazyScopedRegistration2.GetInstance(Scope
>   scope)
>               bei lambda_method(Closure )
>               bei Glimpse.SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorTab.CollectResolvedInstance(InitializationContext
>   context, Func1 instanceProducer)
>               bei SimpleInjector.Container.<>c__DisplayClass52_0.b__0()
>               bei SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
>          InnerException:

This one is thrown at:

> SimpleInjector.dll!SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()    Unbekannt
>       SimpleInjector.dll!SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance(System.Type serviceType)    Unbekannt
>     idee5.Dispatcher.dll!SimpleInjector.SignalR.SimpleInjectorHubActivator.Create(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDescriptor descriptor) Zeile 11  C#
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.DefaultHubManager.ResolveHub(string hubName)    Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.CreateHub(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IRequest request, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDescriptor descriptor, string connectionId, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.StateChangeTracker tracker, bool throwIfFailedToCreate)   Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.OnReceived(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)   Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestPostGroupRead.AnonymousMethod__7()    Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(System.Func func)    Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestPostGroupRead.AnonymousMethod__6(string data) Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport.OnMessage(string message)  Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.DefaultWebSocketHandler.OnMessage(string message) Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler.ProcessWebSocketRequestAsync(System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket webSocket, System.Threading.CancellationToken disconnectToken, System.Func> messageRetriever, object state)   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(object stateMachine)  Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()    Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.OutputAsyncCausalityEvents.AnonymousMethod__0() Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()    Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__0()   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()    Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation..cctor.AnonymousMethod__8_0(object state)   Unbekannt
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.Post.AnonymousMethod__0()    Unbekannt
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.SafeWrapCallback(System.Action action) Unbekannt
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.QueueAsynchronous.AnonymousMethod__0(System.Threading.Tasks.Task _)    Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()  Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()  Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj)   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot)    Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Another suspicious exception is:

> SimpleInjector.ActivationException ist aufgetreten.
>     HResult=-2146233088
>     Message=The SchedulerHub is registered as 'Hybrid Execution Context Scope / Web Request' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of a Hybrid Execution Context Scope / Web Request.
>     Source=SimpleInjector
>     StackTrace:
>          bei SimpleInjector.Scope.GetScopelessInstance[TService,TImplementation](ScopedRegistration`2 registration)
>     InnerException:

This one is thrown at:

> SimpleInjector.dll!SimpleInjector.Scope.GetScopelessInstance(SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.ScopedRegistration registration) Unbekannt
>       SimpleInjector.dll!SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstance(SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.ScopedRegistration registration, SimpleInjector.Scope scope)  Unbekannt
>       SimpleInjector.dll!SimpleInjector.Advanced.Internal.LazyScopedRegistration.GetInstance(SimpleInjector.Scope scope)  Unbekannt
>       [Lightweightfunktion]
>       Glimpse.SimpleInjector.dll!Glimpse.SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorTab.CollectResolvedInstance(SimpleInjector.Advanced.InitializationContext context, System.Func instanceProducer)    Unbekannt
>       SimpleInjector.dll!SimpleInjector.Container.ApplyResolveInterceptor.AnonymousMethod__0()    Unbekannt
>       SimpleInjector.dll!SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()    Unbekannt
>       SimpleInjector.dll!SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance(System.Type serviceType)    Unbekannt
>     idee5.Dispatcher.dll!SimpleInjector.SignalR.SimpleInjectorHubActivator.Create(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDescriptor descriptor) Zeile 11  C#
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.DefaultHubManager.ResolveHub(string hubName)    Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.CreateHub(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IRequest request, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDescriptor descriptor, string connectionId, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.StateChangeTracker tracker, bool throwIfFailedToCreate)   Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.GetHubs.AnonymousMethod__39(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDescriptor descriptor)   Unbekannt
>       System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator.MoveNext()  Unbekannt
>       System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator.MoveNext()   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.List.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable collection)    Unbekannt
>       System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable source)    Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ExecuteHubEvent(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IRequest request, string connectionId, System.Func action)  Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.OnReconnected(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IRequest request, string connectionId) Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestPostGroupRead.AnonymousMethod__5()    Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(System.Func func)    Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestPostGroupRead.AnonymousMethod__4()    Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.ProcessReceiveRequest.AnonymousMethod__1c()  Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.ProcessMessages(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ITransportConnection connection, System.Func initialize)    Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.ProcessReceiveRequest(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ITransportConnection connection)   Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.ProcessRequestCore.AnonymousMethod__e(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport t, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ITransportConnection c)    Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(System.Func func, System.__Canon arg1, System.__Canon arg2)  Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.Then(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Func successor, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport arg1, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ITransportConnection arg2) Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.ProcessRequestCore(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ITransportConnection connection)  Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport.ProcessRequest.AnonymousMethod__2(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.IWebSocket socket)  Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.OwinWebSocketHandler.RunWebSocketHandler.AnonymousMethod__0()   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Startc__DisplayClass1.<b__0>d__3 stateMachine)   Unbekannt
>       Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.OwinWebSocketHandler.RunWebSocketHandler.AnonymousMethod__0()   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()  Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj)   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot)    Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    Unbekannt
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() Unbekannt

Both are caught. And I suspect that's the reason nothing seems to happen and my hub methods are not called.

After some try'n'error sessions I ended up with this container configuration.

```
    public static Container GetInitializeContainer(IAppBuilder app) {
    // configure AutoMapper
    MapperConfiguration mapperConfig = ConfigureMappings();

    // Create the container as usual.
    var container = new Container();
    ScopedLifestyle hybrid = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
        () => container.GetCurrentExecutionContextScope() != null,
        new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle(),
        new WebRequestLifestyle());
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = hybrid;

    // Registering the types
    container.RegisterSingleton(() => mapperConfig.CreateMapper());
    container.RegisterSingleton(app);
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUrlHelperProvider, UrlHelperProvider>();
    // register the singleton services
    container.RegisterSingleton<ICacheService>(new CacheService());
    container.RegisterSingleton<ILoggingService, LoggingService>();

    // register application services
    // get the assembly containing the services 
    Assembly repositoryAssembly = typeof(CompanyService).Assembly;
    // get the services namespace
    string @namespace = typeof(CompanyService).Namespace;
    // register all interfaces in the assembly besides the singletons
    var registrations =
        from type in repositoryAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
        where type.Namespace == @namespace
        where type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name.EndsWith(value: "Service") &&
            i.Name != nameof(ICacheService) && i.Name != nameof(ILoggingService))
        select new { Service = type.GetInterfaces().Single(i => i.Name.EndsWith(value: "Service")), Implementation = type };

    foreach (var reg in registrations) {
        container.Register(reg.Service, reg.Implementation, new WebRequestLifestyle());
    }

    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<ApplicationUserManager>();
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserStore<IdentityUser, Guid>>(() => new UserStore());
    container.RegisterInitializer<ApplicationUserManager>(manager => InitializeUserManager(manager, app));
    // register the role manager
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<ApplicationRoleManager>();
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, Guid>>(() => new RoleStore());
    container.RegisterInitializer<ApplicationRoleManager>(manager => InitializeRoleManager(manager));

    container.Register<Hubs.SchedulerHub, Hubs.SchedulerHub>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    // register the sign in manager
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest(() => AdvancedExtensions.IsVerifying(container)
            ? new OwinContext(new Dictionary<string, object>()).Authentication
            : HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);

    // Register all controllers and filters. Including those in MVC areas
    container.RegisterMvcControllers();
    container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();

    // register OWIN
    app.Use(async (context, next) => {
        using (container.BeginExecutionContextScope()) {
            CallContext.LogicalSetData(name: "IOwinContext", data: context);
            await next();
        }
    });
    container.RegisterSingleton<IOwinContextProvider>(new CallContextOwinContextProvider());

    return container;
}
```

My hub activator:

```
    public class SimpleInjectorHubActivator : IHubActivator {
    public SimpleInjectorHubActivator(Container container) {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHub Create(HubDescriptor descriptor) {
        return (IHub) _container.GetInstance(descriptor.HubType);
    }

    private readonly Container _container;
}
```

My hub dispatcher:

```
public class SimpleInjectorHubDispatcher : HubDispatcher {
    public SimpleInjectorHubDispatcher(Container container, HubConfiguration configuration)
        : base(configuration) {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId) {
        return Invoke(() => base.OnConnected(request, connectionId));
    }

    protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data) {
        return Invoke(() => base.OnReceived(request, connectionId, data));
    }

    protected override Task OnDisconnected(IRequest request, string connectionId,
        bool stopCalled) {
        return Invoke(() => base.OnDisconnected(request, connectionId, stopCalled));
    }

    protected override Task OnReconnected(IRequest request, string connectionId) {
        return Invoke(() => base.OnReconnected(request, connectionId));
    }

    private async Task Invoke(Func<Task> method) {
        using (_container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
            await method();
    }

    private readonly Container _container;
}
```

How can I prevent this exception and get my hub methods being invoked?

Comment: What's the exception message in English?

Comment: And please post the complete stack trace (with inner exception details).

Comment: Hi Steven. I added an english version and the exception appearing beofre in the diagnoe tools.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Had to figure out how I can get more details about the excecptions.

Comment: You left out the inner exception details. Please add those.

Comment: And please describe when those exceptions are thrown. You are posting two exceptions that seem to be thrown at different moments in time. Please describe when this happens.

Comment: First of all. Thank you for your patience. he stack trace ends with "InnerException: " because there is none. It is null at that point.

Comment: I created a much smaller project with the same or at a least similar issue. No dispatcher, much smaller container config. Being new to stackoverflow I have no idea how to act "polite" now. New topic or edit/rewrite the original one?
((The stack trace doesn't show more details in that project. But it might eliminate some scenarios, due to the lower complexity.))

Comment: Your excepton starts at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance(), but what is calling that method. Part of the stack trace is still missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115282/discussion-between-bdongus-and-steven).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stack trace I see that the default `HubDispatcher` is invoked, not your custom `SimpleInjectorHubDispatcher`. This means that no scope is applied and this is probably the reason why you are getting the message "the instance is requested outside the context of a Hybrid Execution Context Scope / Web Request."

You should register your `SimpleInjectorHubDispatcher` as follows:
I think the error is in the following line:

```
var dispatcher = new SimpleInjectorHubDispatcher(container, config);
config.Resolver.Register(typeof(HubDispatcher), dispatcher);
```

Comment: Just one more thing. I register typeof(SimpleInjectorHubDispatcher). Using typeof(HubDispatcher), the hub wasn't created.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Stevens chat support and some deep digging I found the flaw. I mixed up the life styles of the hub and the used services.

The hard part was to gather any details about the silently failing SignalR call. If anyone else runs into such a situation I would like to share two hints on how to gather more information:

- Have a close look at your debug output and look for suspicious exceptions.
- Tell Visual Studio to break if those occur.

That way you can get hold of the stack trace, inner exception, etc. Otherwise you won't find the reason.
In my case I monitored SimpleInjector.ActivationException and Steven helped me to find the reason.